# How can I alter a column to a user-defined type in Postgres if there are already values that won't match?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table with a column that is currently of type "character varying (50)".  I want to change the type of that column to a user-defined type to restrict the allowable values to those specified in my user-defined type "fruit_types".

Is there a way that I can use an ALTER COLUMN statement to basically say "convert the existing values in this column to  one of the pre-defined fruit_types and if you cannot convert, set to *other* "?

Here is my user-defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE food.fruit_types AS ENUM
    ('apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'other');
```

And here is the statement that will work as long as all of the text matches a value in my user-defined type:

```
ALTER TABLE food.fruit
  ALTER COLUMN fruit_type TYPE food.fruit_types USING 
   (fruit_type::TEXT::food.fruit_types);
```

But if I have a value in that column that isn't in the user-defined type (for example "kiwi") then I get this error message:

```
invalid input value for enum food.fruit_types: "kiwi"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether a label exists in an enum type with [the function `enum_range():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-enum.html)

```
ALTER TABLE food.fruit
    ALTER COLUMN fruit_type TYPE food.fruit_types USING (
        CASE 
            WHEN fruit_type = ANY(enum_range(NULL::food.fruit_types)::text[]) 
            THEN fruit_type::food.fruit_types
            ELSE 'other'::food.fruit_types
        END)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks for your help!